# ML.net code program cant find input column, out of range exception when training algorithm

Tags: c#, .net, ml.net

When i train my algorithm  an exception in my model:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Could not find input column 'Features' '

I'm pretty sure i am passing in the correct variables into my pipeline property, however I am aware that ML has a new version out so things are deprecated. although can't spot any here:

```
var model = pipeLine.Fit(dataView);
```

is what is erroring

```
var pipeLine = mlContext.Transforms
     .Text.FeaturizeText("FeedBack", "Features")
    .Append(mlContext.BinaryClassification.Trainers.FastTree(numberOfLeaves: 50, numberOfTrees: 50, minimumExampleCountPerLeaf: 1));
```

is where my model is coming from

and

```
var mlContext = new MLContext();

IDataView dataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(trainingData);
```

is where my dataView is coming from.

This is my trainingData

```cs
static void LoadTrainingData() {
    trainingData.Add(new FeedBackTrainingData() {
        FeedBackText = "this is good",
        IsGood = true
    });

    trainingData.Add(new FeedBackTrainingData() {
        FeedBackText = "this is horrible",
        IsGood = true
    });

    trainingData.Add(new FeedBackTrainingData() {
        FeedBackText = "this is horrible",
        IsGood = false
    });

    trainingData.Add(new FeedBackTrainingData() {
        FeedBackText = "this is average and ok",
        IsGood = true
    });

    trainingData.Add(new FeedBackTrainingData() {
        FeedBackText = "bloody awful",
        IsGood = false
    });

    trainingData.Add(new FeedBackTrainingData() {
        FeedBackText = "bad",
        IsGood = false
    });

    trainingData.Add(new FeedBackTrainingData() {
        FeedBackText = "better",
        IsGood = true
    });

    trainingData.Add(new FeedBackTrainingData() {
        FeedBackText = "so much nicer",
        IsGood = true
    });

    trainingData.Add(new FeedBackTrainingData() {
        FeedBackText = "shitty terrible",
        IsGood = false
    });

    trainingData.Add(new FeedBackTrainingData() {
        FeedBackText = "worse",
        IsGood = false
    });

    trainingData.Add(new FeedBackTrainingData() {
        FeedBackText = "nice and good",
        IsGood = true
    });


    trainingData.Add(new FeedBackTrainingData() {
        FeedBackText = "soooo bad",
        IsGood = false
    });
}
```

```
    class FeedBackTrainingData
{

    [LoadColumn(0)]
    [ColumnName("label")]
    public bool IsGood { get; set; }

    [LoadColumn(1)]
    public string FeedBackText { get; set; }


}
```

my model

Comment: We need to see your data

Comment: @ZakkDiaz please see edit :)

Comment: Perhaps the featurizetext parameters are backwards. If I recall the output column is the first parameter.

Comment: You mentioned something about deprecated label attributes here. Can you elaborate? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.textcatalog.featurizetext?view=ml-dotnet

It seems that FeaturizeText expects the parameters (outputColumnName, inputColumnName)

Your data model looks like this

```
{
    FeedBackText = "this is good",
    IsGood = true
}
```

But you are looking for a column called "Features" to shove into a "FeedBack" column.

```
 .Text.FeaturizeText("FeedBack", "Features")
```

Try something like

```
 .Text.FeaturizeText("Features", "FeedBackText")
```

Comment: hmm doesnt work either, i switched them around and now it says 'could not find input column 'FeedBackText'

Comment: The answer seems to be wrong then. That documentation has a very clear example on how to use it though so maybe spend some time implementing their version and compare it to yours.

Comment: what do you think about my FeedBackTrainingData class?  perhaps the attributes are wrong?

Comment: This actually worked! turns out the label attributes of my data class was deprecated... so there were 2 issues and this fixed one! many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found a solution by using the "SdcaLogisticRegression"

```
var pipeLine = mlContext.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText(outputColumnName: "Features", inputColumnName: "FeedBackText") .Append(mlContext.BinaryClassification.Trainers.SdcaLogisticRegression(labelColumnName: "label", featureColumnName: "Features"));
```